# How to test a function in React Component with Jest + Enzyme?

Tags: jestjs, enzyme

I am using the testing-library/jest-dom + Enzyme to do the unit testing.and here I need to test a funtion inside a React function.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

function Component1() {

    useEffect( async () => {
         fetchSomeData();
    }, [])

    const fetchSomeData = async () =>{
        console.log('fetchSomeData')

    }

    return <div>Component1</div>;
}

export default Component1;
```

and my test file:

```
Enzyme.configure({adapter:new Adapter()})

describe('Name of the group', () => {

    it('should ', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow( <Component1/>)
        expect(wrapper.exists());
    });

});
```

in fact I don't need to test the correctness , I just need the code be covered in jest. but whatever I tried , it seems not covered by jest:
[image]

Comment: You cannot access local variable/function outside the component. Test the effects that it causes. In the question it does nothing so it likely differs from real code.

Comment: you mean , I can put the function into a useEffect and test it ?

Comment: I mean that you need to test what it does to a component without calling it directly. You didn't show how it's used. And it doesn't need to be a part of the component because it doesn't use anything from its scope.

Comment: I need to test to simulate fetch some data in useEffect , and my first problem is , it is not covered by jest just as the picture shown.

Comment: shallow doesn't support useEffect, use mount. You can make a delay of the same amount in the test, `await null; expect(...)`. fetchSomeData doesn't do anything useful. In this case you can spy on console.log and assert that it was called.